# suddenly Jenkins doesn't do pod install anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cocoapods

Pod install was working until it suddenly stopped with the error ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII Jenkins.
I tried adding export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" to my bash_profile and sourcing from it in terminal but that did not help. I cannot find the ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc files. Pod install also works in terminal but not Jenkins

- pod install --verbose
  [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
  Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  [0m
  Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1109: warning: The environment variable HTTP_PROXY is discouraged.  Use http_proxy.

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod install --verbose
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.4 (20F71)
       Xcode : 12.5 (12E262)
         Git : git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : cocoapods - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ e6eac0770b8860823225a364d6e56c215581d90b
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
project 'FPExperience.xcodeproj'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


platform :ios, '10.0'


post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

#### Error

```
ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/config.rb:277:in `split'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/config.rb:277:in `hash_from_file_content'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/config.rb:259:in `extract_hash'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/config.rb:64:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb:241:in `new'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb:241:in `config'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb:97:in `resolve_build_setting'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb:102:in `resolve_build_setting'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/configuration_list.rb:78:in `block in get_setting'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/configuration_list.rb:77:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/configuration_list.rb:77:in `get_setting'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/native_target.rb:55:in `resolved_build_setting'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:226:in `block in compute_swift_version_from_targets'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:220:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:220:in `inject'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:220:in `compute_swift_version_from_targets'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:45:in `compute_results'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1187:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1187:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1185:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1185:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1180:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:106:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=invalid+byte+sequence+in+US-ASCII&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- Missing install instructions for linux (install deps)
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9956 [open] [2 comments]
  05 Mar 2021
- invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1036 [closed] [10 comments]
  22 Apr 2021
- CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding and it aborts  to run pod
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333 [closed] [9 comments]
  7 weeks ago

and 21 more at:
[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=invalid%20byte%20sequence%20in%20US-ASCII&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=invalid%20byte%20sequence%20in%20US-ASCII&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add following to section titled environment {
in pipeline

```
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```